# onActivityResults reseting values

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, onactivityresult

I'm testing one functionality of an app in different devices and it happens in one of them: 
When I calls onActivityResult, it works normally but in the second time it's called, it reset the previous data registered in the last call. It works normally in most of devices but this one exceptionally cleans the view when comes from activity result. 
So basically when I selected the second image either from gallery or for camera intent, it resets the previous selected file.
This is how the data it's being retrieved:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        val selectedImage: Uri?
        if(requestCode == GALLERY_1 || requestCode == GALLERY_2 || requestCode == GALLERY_3) {
            selectedImage = data!!.data
            configImagePersistentPermission(selectedImage)
        } else {
            val bitmap = data!!.extras!!.get("data") as Bitmap
            selectedImage = configImagePathUri(requireContext(), bitmap)
        }
        try {
            when (requestCode) {
                GALLERY_1 -> {
                    binding.imageDoc1.setImageURI(selectedImage)
                    configResetImageView(0)
                }
                CAMERA_1 -> {
                    binding.imageDoc1.setImageURI(selectedImage)
                    configResetImageView(0)
                }
                GALLERY_2 -> {
                    binding.imageDoc2.setImageURI(selectedImage)
                    configResetImageView(1)
                }
                CAMERA_2 -> {
                    binding.imageDoc2.setImageURI(selectedImage)
                    configResetImageView(1)
                }
                GALLERY_3 -> {
                    binding.imageDoc3.setImageURI(selectedImage)
                    configResetImageView(2)
                }
                CAMERA_3 -> {
                    binding.imageDoc3.setImageURI(selectedImage)
                    configResetImageView(2)
                }
            }
            imageList.add(selectedImage.toString())
        } catch (e: Exception){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

How to prevent losing the previous recorded data in this scenario? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is "the previous recorded data"? Bear in mind that your process can be terminated at any point when you are not in the foreground. You need to take steps not to lose any data when you launch a third-party activity. For small data and short-term process termination, use the saved instance state `Bundle` or things that build atop of it (e.g., `SavedStateHandle`, `rememberSaveable()`). Beyond that, store stuff in files or databases. Just remember to [request persistable permissions](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/08/08/uri-access-lifetime-still-shorter-than-you-might-think.html).

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. The previous data is basically images requested from gallery or camera intent. I'm able to select one, but when I trigger the onactivityresult again, it clears the previous selected image. All of those images from gallery already is persistable. Only in this specific device it is happening, in all of others that I tested, the images does not disappear when trigger onactivityresult for second or third time.

Comment: That suggests that your process is being terminated on that particular device. Make sure that you save your data before launching a third-party activity, in case your process is terminated while that other app is in the foreground.

Comment: could you explain a little how to do it properly? since I'm saving a range between one to three images, how should I do it properly? I read a few examples about save and restore saved instances but I'm not sure how to implement it properly.

Comment: Store `image1`, `image2`, and `image3` in the saved instance state `Bundle`, using `null` to indicate "there is no image in that slot". If you feel the need, also save `imageCount` in the saved instance state `Bundle`, representing the count of images.